# How to fix can't import javax in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, crud

how to fix javax can't import, I'm using eclipse latest build, somehow on my laptop javax get error but i using my friends laptop everything is ok, I don't get any error, how to resolve this error on my pc? should i install something? I've been reinstall my eclipse but it's the same error come.

example :`import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;'

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3iAI.jpg)

Comment: From where does their machine get that package / those classes?

Answer (score 0):

Add this jar file to your build path

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/persistence-api-1.0.jar

And make sure that you have added jre at your lib.

Comment: how to import javax? i've been install presistence but still get error on my code like the picture